# MPLAB Program won`t recognize xc.h header

Tags: microcontroller, mplabx

I am trying to learn how to program my PIC microcontoller (specifically a PIC24FJ128gc010 MCU), but having some trouble with what should be a very simple program.
I can't declare any pins as outputs or inputs, or do anything really because the
`#include <xc.h>`
has a yellow underline. I control clicked it to investigate more and MPLAB says that the header file for my specific microcontorller cannot be found, but I was able to find it in my xc16 installation directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc16\v1.50\support\PIC24F).

Comment: Does your project include paths point to your folder that you found?

Comment: I`m not sure, how would I check that?

Comment: Right click the project, go to properties, find the source paths and make sure it's included.

Comment: Sorry, could be more specific, I am in the Project Properties window, where do I go from there?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where it is on XC16, for XC32, it's under the XC32 (Global Options), "common include dirs".

Comment: Hmm I added and it`s still telling me no such file or directory

Comment: There are 3 different file formats to choose from )folder names of the specific header file) "gld", "h", and "inc". Which one should I select? Also when I choose one of them MPLAB is showing nothing in the folder, which makes me think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Never mind, it seem to be working now. Now to figure out what else is wrong with my code haha. Thank you.

Comment: What version of MPLAB / MPLABX and XC16?

Comment: This is turning into a "How do I use MPLAB to write code for a PIC" question and, as such, is far too broad...

Answer (score 3):

Try to add all the items from the /include folder that is locate where you installed the xc8 or xc16.

To do this, right-click the project and go to properties.

Go to XC8 global option (or XC16) and click on XC8 compiler (or XC16).

Click the three dots righ next to "Include Directories".

Click browse and  find the following directory \Program Files\Microchip\xc8\vx.xx\pic\include, there you will find some other folders, you will add all of them, one by
one.

Hit apply.

Comment: Only Legacy and proc  folders are needed, c90 and c99 throw some other errors.